# C++ class inheritance

Tags: c++, class

Im having a little problem with classes.

In code:

```
class A
{
public:
     int num;
     sayNum() { cout<<num;}
};

class B : public A
{
public:
     sayNum() { cout<<"my num is: "<<num;}
};

/*somewhere else...*/
A foo[10];

B something;
something.num=10;

foo[0]=something;

foo[0].sayNum();
/*...*/
```

When I call foo[0].sayNum(); it prints "10", and I would like it to print "my num is: 10". I can't change the type of the array. Note that it is just an example code, if I paste mine here it would be hard to understand :D)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
foo[0]=something;
```

*copies* something into the array. Because the type of `something` (i.e. class B) is not the same as the type of `foo[0]` (i.e. class A), there is a conversion. In this case, `something` will be *sliced*, and only the A part will survive.

The net result is that `foo[0]` still contains an object with type `class A`, and thus the "my num is" will *never* be output.

Changing `sayNum()` to be virtual, which is good advice to solve other problems your code will show, won't help in this case.

How to solve it, depends on what you want to achieve. Possible solutions are:

- Change the array to contain **pointers**: `A* foo[10];` Note: this means you'll have to use 'new' and 'delete'.
- Use a **std::vector** instead of an array: `std::vector<A*> foo;` Additional benefit: a vector can grow and shrink on demand.
- Use **smart pointers**: `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A> > foo;` Additional benefit: no worries about `delete` anymore.

But without knowing what you want to achieve, it is impossible to suggest the correct approach.

Answer (score 4):

**1. You should avoid slicing**
You should use `A*` instead of `A`. This could help you understand why: [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/274626/1168156)

**2. You should declare `sayNum()` function of a class `A` as `virtual`**
Definition of class `A` should look like this:

```
class A
{
public:
    int num;
    virtual void sayNum() { cout << num; }
};
```

Then your code as you say `somewhere else` could look like this:

```
A* foo[10];

B something;
something.num=10;

foo[0] = &something;

foo[0]->sayNum();
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare the function sayNum to be virtual in the definition of A:

```
virtual void sayNum() { cout<<num;}
```

Edit: thanks to Sjoerd 's comment - this will still not help you. If you want to make use of the polymorphism you need to create an array of pointers to class A rather then an array of class A.

Comment: Although it is a good advice, it's not good enough in this case. The assignment to the array slices the object, and only the A-part is copied into the array.

Comment: @Sjoerd so how can I store an array of different classes?

Comment: @kittyPL By storing pointers (or smart pointers) to a common base class of the types you want to store.

Answer (score 1):

No, by assigning `something` to `foo[0]` you convert it to an A.

This is similar to assigning a `float` to an `int` - you lose all the decimals.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your missing the return types for your functions in each of your class. Say you want a return type to be `void`:

   `void sayNum() { cout<<num;}`
2. When accessing the array elements, use the subscripts on array *object*:

   For example:

   `foo[0]=something;`

Comment: This is not the problem he is having.

Comment: I agree. I added the comment to indicate that even if the problems you pointed out are fixed, his problems will still be present.

Comment: sorry for that, I was writing it just for example, didnt even tried to compile :)